# I set up a virtual env to download the pipenv package. How should I add the resulting directory to PATH?

Tags: python, terminal, pipenv

I installed Python 3.7 in my MacBook Air (Mojave 10.14). First, I got “Command line tools”, then Homebrew and finally python 3.7. I followed the instructions I found on: https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/#install3-osx

The problem started when I wanted to install Pipenv. In my first attempt on Terminal, I received a message saying: “Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied”. After reading, I discovered that the best solution was to create a virtual environment to download pipenv. So I wrote the commands:

```
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate 
python -m pip install -- user pipenv
```

It worked but seems that I need to add this directory to PATH.I received the following answers on Terminal.

```
The script virtualenv is installed in '/Users/marianasierra/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script virtualenv-clone is installed in '/Users/marianasierra/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '/Users/marianasierra/Library/Python/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I tried to add the directory to PATH, but I don’t think is working, since I’m still seeing the (env) on Terminal. What should I do in this case? How this especific directory should be added to PATH?

My last commands were:

```
(env) Marianas-MacBook-Air:~ marianasierra$  python -m site --user-base /Users/marianasierra/Library/Python/3.7
(env) Marianas-MacBook-Air:~ marianasierra$ export PATH="$PATH:/Users/marianasierra/Library/Python/3.7/bin"
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can not reproduce this problem. Seems like problem with path to binaries.

Answer (score 0):

But why you should do such a thing? Then you may confront issues

```
export PATH=$(which pipenv):$PTTH
```